# Relation between stage.draw and stage.getBatch.draw Libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am new to libgdx stage, and is very confuse about stage.draw and stage.getbatch.draw. Is the following codes a proper practice?

```
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(101,10,0,2);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();

    elapseTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    stage.getBatch().begin();
    stage.getBatch().draw(texture.animation.getKeyFrame(elapseTime,true),locationX,locationY);
    stage.getBatch().end();
}
```

I'm using stage.draw to perform some action to my ui button, and stage.getbatch.draw to perform my texture animaiton. Are them referring to the same sprite batch?

Comment: There's nothing wrong about your code above. `Stage.draw` uses it's own batch reference, so yes, `stage.getBatch` gives you a reference to that same batch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)